# Why has <h:message> tag showSummary=false per default?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I learned to put a `<h:message for="@previous">` after input fields and create errors with new `FacesMessage()` with only a summary text and "" as detail parameter.

On the other hand, both `<h:message>` and Primeface's `<p:message>` default to showSummary=false and showDetail=true.

Why doesn't h:message has the defaults the other way around?
Do I misunderstand the purpose of h:message?

Comment: Your question is confusing because whatever you state about the defaults is [not](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/messages.html) [true](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/6.0/core/primefaces-p/messages.html).

Comment: The context help in NetBeans 8.1 says:

Library: http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html, http://java.sun.com/jsf/html (Html Basic)
Tag: message
showSummary
Flag indicating whether the summary portion of displayed messages should be included. Default value is "false".

The p:message says:

Library: http://primefaces.org/ui (PrimeFaces)
Tag: message
showSummary
Specifies if the summary of the FacesMessage should be displayed. Default is false.

Apparently it changed recently:

* http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/

Comment: It seems to be a typo in the taglib. If I browse the dependencies and open primefaces-5.0.jar, I find META-INF/primefaces-p.taglib.xml which contains:

`
<tag-name>message</tag-name>
...
 <attribute>
   <description><![CDATA[Specifies if the summary of the FacesMessage should be displayed. Default is false.]]></description>
   <name>showSummary</name>
`

Comment: And btw, you linked to the API docs of "messages", not "message" - the two tags have opposite defaults!